# Convert 6,4,3, even 2 digit numbers from import to 2 decimal price

Tags: excel, decimal, digit

I have been struggling to find a solution to this. I have a CSV file with an unusual pricing format and I need to update an eCommerce database with it.

### The prices in CSV looks like this:

```
258662
349387
304
50
```

---

So, last two digits is the 2nd decimal. 
I need to mass process these prices like this:

```
258662 to 2586,62
86923 to 869,23
304 to 3,04
50 to 0,50
```

I hope I could explain my need properly.

Answer (score 1):

simply divide by 100; assuming that all the prices are stored in column A of your Excel sheet and you want to have the new prices in column B, the formula would be, e.g. for cell B1: `=A1/100`

Comment: FLIR, I feel like a total dumb at the moment. I have been working with excel and databases for such long time and couldn't think nor find about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem; sometimes we just get "blind" for the easy solution :-)  If you like my answer, please accept it as correct. Thanks.